# Why does it ask me that the keys are of type text if they already are?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, nonetype

```
import os
import tweepy as tw


consumer_key=os.environ.get("CONSUMER_KEY")
consumer_secret=os.environ.get("CONSUMER_SECRET")
access_token=os.environ.get("ACCESS_TOKEN")
access_token_secret=os.environ.get("ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET")

auth = tw.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tw.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)
```

I added my credentials in an .env file, but when I run the code I get the following error: TypeError: Consumer key must be string or bytes, not NoneType

Comment: Are you loading the .env file? Otherwise the code will not be able to retrieve the values (I don't see you using dotenv anywhere in the code)